# Is this a bra form of the following coherent state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, rotation

I define spin coherent state as,

$$\left|z\right>_j  =  \left(1+|z|^2\right)^{-j}\exp(z J_-)\left|j \ j\right> $$

where $J_-$ is the annihilation angular momentum  operator,
If I use these notations,
\begin{align}
\left<\zeta\right|&=\sum_{n} \zeta^*_{n}\left<j \  n\right| \\
   \left|\zeta^*\right>&=\sum_{n} \zeta^*_{n}\left|j \  n\right>\\
 \left<\zeta^*\right|&=\sum_{n} \zeta_{n}\left <j \ n\right|
 \end{align}
Can I write  the definition of bra state of this spin coherent state in this form,

$$\left<z\right| = \left(1+|z|^{2}\right)^{-j}\exp(z J_+)\left <j \ j \right|$$

I appreciate any help

Comment: I’ve tried to make your question easier to read with some whitespace changes. Please check whether I have introduced any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Almost: you have to recall that taking the Hermitian conjugate requires switching the order of the operators. You thus find
$$\langle z|=(1+|z|^2)^{-j}\langle j j|\exp(z^* J_+).$$ Note that I have also performed the complex conjugation on $z$ in the exponential, and that the scalar (non-operator) term $(1+|z|^2)^{-j}$ commutes with all of the operators and can thus be put on either side of them.

Comment: Not sure it’s wise to provide explicit answer to such elementary problems.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero duly noted, will refrain from being so explicit